# Rust mutable borrow of Iterator yielding owned value fails in loop

Tags: rust, iterator, borrow-checker, ownership

My practical problem is solved by a workaround, but I have no idea why the workaround works and the original version does not.

I have these types:

```rust
struct Lexer<'source> { ... }
impl<'source> Iterator for Lexer<'source> {
    type Item = Token<'source>;
    ...
}

struct Func<'source> { ... }
```

These functions do not work:

```rust
fn parse_tokens<'source>(lexer: &'source mut Lexer<'source>) -> Vec<Func> {
    let mut funcs = Vec::new();
    loop {
        let Some(t) = lexer.next() else { break; }
        funcs.push(parse_fn(lexer));
    }
    funcs
}
pub fn parse_fn<'source>(lexer: &'source mut Lexer<'source>) -> Func {
    // Get the name of the function.
    // TODO: replace all of these unwraps and panics with error handling.
    let t = lexer.next().unwrap();
    if t.kind != TokenKind::Identifier { panic!() }
    let ident = t.value;

    let mut body = Vec::new();
    loop {
        let Some(t) = lexer.next() else { break };
        match t.kind {
            TokenKind::Keyword(Keyword::End) => break,
            TokenKind::Int(num) => body.push(Op::PushInt(num)),
            kind => todo!("parsing of {kind:?}"),
        }
    }

    Func {
        ident,
        body
    }
}
```

Compilation fails with the following error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*lexer` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/parse.rs:44:23
   |
41 | pub fn parse_tokens<'source>(lexer: &'source mut Lexer<'source>) -> Vec<Func> {
   |                     ------- lifetime `'source` defined here
...
44 |         let Some(t) = lexer.next() else { break };
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
45 |         match t.kind {
46 |             TokenKind::Keyword(Keyword::Fn) => funcs.push(parse_fn(lexer)),
   |                                                           ---------------
   |                                                           |        |
   |                                                           |        first mutable borrow occurs here
   |                                                           argument requires that `*lexer` is borrowed for `'source`

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*lexer` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/parse.rs:46:68
   |
41 | pub fn parse_tokens<'source>(lexer: &'source mut Lexer<'source>) -> Vec<Func> {
   |                     ------- lifetime `'source` defined here
...
46 |             TokenKind::Keyword(Keyword::Fn) => funcs.push(parse_fn(lexer)),
   |                                                           ---------^^^^^-
   |                                                           |        |
   |                                                           |        `*lexer` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop
   |                                                           argument requires that `*lexer` is borrowed for `'source`
```

However - this is the part that is bizarre to me - if I don't use mutable borrows, and instead pass ownership back and forth, the code compiles and works as intended.

In particular, by updating the functions and their signatures like so:

```rust
pub fn parse_tokens<'source>(mut lexer: Lexer<'source>) -> Vec<Func> {
    ...
    TokenKind::Keyword(Keyword::Fn) => {
        let func;
        (lexer, func) = parse_fn(lexer);
        funcs.push(func);
    }
    ...
}
pub fn parse_fn<'source>(mut lexer: Lexer<'source>) -> (Lexer<'source>, Func) {
    ...
    (lexer, Func {
        ident,
        body
    })
}
```

I was under the impression that the first example doesn't work because the borrow checker believes `funcs` will contain data pointed to by `lexer`, and `funcs` outlives the mutable borrow. But given the version that compiles, this cannot be the case.

Any help/explanation towards understanding this would be greatly appreciated.

If further information or a full working example is required, I will be happy to provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you combined two different lifetimes:

```rust
fn parse_tokens<'source>(lexer: &'source mut Lexer<'source>) -> Vec<Func> {
    ...

pub fn parse_fn<'source>(lexer: &'source mut Lexer<'source>) -> Func {
    ...
```

The lifetime in `&mut` is the lifetime *for which the `Lexer` is borrowed*. The lifetime in `<>` is the lifetime the *tokens borrow from*.

By using the same lifetime parameter for both, you're saying “the `Lexer` is borrowed for exactly as long as its items are valid”. This produces the result that you can only use it exactly once (and sometimes not even that) and then it becomes borrowed for the rest of its existence.

In general, you should *never* write `&'a mut Foo<'a>`, for any type `Foo`; this will always result in the “borrowed for the rest of its existence” effect.

(To be precise, this only happens when *invariance* is involved; in general, `&'a mut T` is invariant in `T`, meaning roughly that any lifetimes in `T` cannot be coerced to being *shorter*. However, this is only true for `&mut`, so `&'a Foo<'a>` is often acceptable, and when it isn't, it's because you need to copy `Foo<'b>`s out of `&'a Foo<'b>` that are longer lived than `'a`; it's never a problem for inputs to functions that don't return or any borrows or transmit them elsewhere.)

Instead, use distinct lifetimes:

```rust
fn parse_tokens<'lex, 'source>(lexer: &'lex mut Lexer<'source>) -> Vec<Func> {
    ...

pub fn parse_fn<'lex, 'source>(lexer: &'lex mut Lexer<'source>) -> Func {
    ...
```

In fact, you can even omit one or both of the lifetime names entirely, because the [lifetime elision rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-elision.html) do the right thing in this case. (“Each elided lifetime in input position becomes a distinct lifetime parameter.”)

```rust
fn parse_tokens(lexer: &mut Lexer<'_>) -> Vec<Func> {
    ...

pub fn parse_fn(lexer: &mut Lexer<'_>) -> Func {
    ...
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for this answer! Clears it up perfectly.